# How combine a function that returns list of compound type with function that summarizes that list

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have the following [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y0uZWlF5) that describes the data and process.

In a nutshell, I have a table with a field `levels::My_Compound_Type[]`.

I want to pull several records from this table, `unnest` the field `levels` before summarizing the `field_levels`.  The summary is the same compound type.

I'm new to manipulating arrays, specifically, going in and out of a collection of my `My_Compound_Type` using `ARRAY` and `Table`.  In addition to there is likely a more streamlined approach, I suspect there is a type annotation required to make it work.

#### Data table

```sql
create type Level AS (Value text, Count integer);

create table core.Levels (
    project_id uuid         not null,
    path       text         not null,
    hash       text         not null,
    field_idx  smallint     not null,
    levels     Level[]      not null,

    constraint pk_Levels
        primary key (project_id, path, field_idx)
);
```

#### Collection of `levels`

```sql
create or replace function get_levels(
    IN _project_id uuid,
    IN _request Field_Lookup[]
) returns table(value text, count integer) as $$

    -- lookup the array of fields, unnest the list of arrays
    
       select unnest(levels)
       from core.Levels 
       where project_id = _project_id
       and (path, field_idx) = ANY (_request)
    
$$ language sql security definer
```

#### Summary of `levels`

```sql
-- more for type casting
create table tb_Levels (
  value text,
  count integer
);

create or replace function get_levels_sum(
    IN _project_id uuid,
    IN _request Field_Lookup[]
) returns table(value text, count bigint) as $$

  begin
  
    INSERT INTO tb_Levels
    SELECT (get_levels($1, $2)).*;

    return query
    select t.value, sum(t.count) 
        from tb_Levels t
        group by t.value
        order by sum(t.count) DESC;

  end;
  
$$ language plpgsql security definer
```

#### The task

Combine the two function calls. Ideally, with zero side-effects i.e., only use a temporary table if one is required during the processing.

#### Update - re-framing the question

The transitions go something like this.  The use of `ARRAY` as the collection type is only required to `unnest` what is returned from the select statement.

```hs
go:: table (path, field_idx, ARRAY level)  // select 
-> ARRAY of ARRAY level                    // unnest 
-> ARRAY level                             // aggregate
-> ARRAY level
```

The aggregation is

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION combine_levels_fn(
  acc Level,
  next_level Level
) returns Level as $$
     select ( 
        coalesce ( ($1).value, ($2).value ), 
        ($1).count + ($2).count
     );
$$ language sql security definer;


CREATE AGGREGATE combine_levels (level)
(
    sfunc = combine_levels_fn,
    stype = level,
    initcond = '(NULL,0)'
);
```

#### Closing entry

In the end, the above approach, while it may be useful at a later time, did not solve the issue.  The key issue with using this custom aggregating function is that I need to perform a `group by` operation using a key inside the composite type.  Pulling that key out... at this point, it makes no sense not to use the natural sql approach.

The "solution" was to stick with the two function approach.  The api exposes the `get_levels` function.  It uses a temp table to compute the summary.

```sql
function get_levels(
    IN _project_id uuid,
    IN _request Field_Lookup[]
) returns setof Level as $$

    begin
        create temp table tmp_data as
        select (go_get_levels($1,$2)).*;

        return query
        select value, sum(count)::integer
            from tmp_data
            group by value
            order by sum(count) DESC;

        drop table tmp_data;
        return;

    end;

$$ language plpgsql security definer;
```

This function relies on the following to retrieve the data from the data table. It returns a `table`; the only way I could find to "type annotate" sufficiently for the `get_levels` function to accomplish the task of `ARRAY MyComposite -> Table(MyComposite.value, MyComposite.count)`; fodder for the summary.

```sql
create or replace function go_get_levels(
    IN _project_id uuid,
    IN _request Field_Lookup[]
) returns table(value text, count integer) as $$

    -- lookup the data, unnest the list of arrays
       select unnest(core.Levels.values)
       from core.Levels
       where project_id = $1
       and (path, field_idx) = ANY ($2);

$$ language sql security definer;
```

Strictly speaking, this is not an answer.  I'm sure there is a better, more "idiomatic" way to leverage the power of using an array as I have to avoid having to add 3 extra table to optimize what I would otherwise have to do (2 of them to host a map from hash and path::text to smallint id as a FK).

In any event, I don't think there was a way to avoid "realizing" the temp table.  It makes intuitive sense that I would need a table to exploit the "natural" approach to generating a summary.

Comment: What is the combined function supposed to return?

Comment: @RichardHuxton A collection of `Level`,  `(value, count)`.

Comment: ... "a collection" could be an ARRAY or table.